# How to style an element to ignore the padding of its parent?

Tags: html, css

CSS

```
div {
   padding: 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div><button>test</button><p>this is some text</p></div>
```

Is there a way to have the `button` ignore the padding and hug the top right corner of the parent `div`, without affecting the 20px around the `p`?

I felt like maybe there's something I could do with the `position` attribute, but from my brief research, it doesn't seem to do what I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can EITHER use position, or negative margins:

Position:

```
div {
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}
div button {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Negative margin:

```
div {
  padding: 20px;
}
button {
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
button {
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
  top: -20px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r13tr5Lt/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px; }
  
div {
  padding: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  position:relative; }
  
div p {
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px; }
```

```html
<div>
    <p>This is paragraph inside a div.</p>
</div>
```